# error: no type named 'IOStreamFactory' in namespace 'Aws' GCC

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-cpp

Issues setting up AWS CPP SDK. [Following the hello_s3 example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/build-cmake.html). compiler throws the error;

```
...include/aws/core/http/HttpClientFactory.h:60:123: error: no type named 'IOStreamFactory' in namespace 'Aws'

 AWS_CORE_API std::shared_ptr<HttpRequest> CreateHttpRequest(const Aws::String& uri, HttpMethod method, const Aws::IOStreamFactory& streamFactory);
[build]                                                                                                                      ~~~~~^
```

- the example code

```
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/s3/S3Client.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <aws/core/auth/AWSCredentialsProviderChain.h>
using namespace Aws;
using namespace Aws::Auth;

/*
 *  A "Hello S3" starter application which initializes an Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) client
 *  and lists the Amazon S3 buckets in the selected region.
 *
 *  main function
 *
 *  Usage: 'hello_s3'
 *
 */

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Aws::SDKOptions options;
    // Optionally change the log level for debugging.~~~~
//   options.loggingOptions.logLevel = Utils::Logging::LogLevel::Debug;
    Aws::InitAPI(options); // Should only be called once.
    int result = 0;
    {
        Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration clientConfig;
        // Optional: Set to the AWS Region (overrides config file).
        // clientConfig.region = "us-east-1";
               
        // You don't normally have to test that you are authenticated. But the S3 service permits anonymous requests, thus the s3Client will return "success" and 0 buckets even if you are unauthenticated, which can be confusing to a new user. 
        auto provider = Aws::MakeShared<DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain>("alloc-tag");
        auto creds = provider->GetAWSCredentials();
        if (creds.IsEmpty()) {
            std::cerr << "Failed authentication" << std::endl;
        }

        Aws::S3::S3Client s3Client(clientConfig);
        auto outcome = s3Client.ListBuckets();

        if (!outcome.IsSuccess()) {
            std::cerr << "Failed with error: " << outcome.GetError() << std::endl;
            result = 1;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Found " << outcome.GetResult().GetBuckets().size()
                      << " buckets\n";
            for (auto &bucket: outcome.GetResult().GetBuckets()) {
                std::cout << bucket.GetName() << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    Aws::ShutdownAPI(options); // Should only be called once.
    return result;
}
```

- the Aws namespace has `#include <cstdlib>` in its utils definition. Unsure how to correct the error I have with the namespace in this new setup? Could clang on mac be compiling with c++98 even with c++11 required in the cmake? I get warning like;

```
warning: defaulted function definitions are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
[build]                 virtual ~MemorySystemInterface() = default;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is regularly compiled and tested on Macs, and this error has not been seen.
Are you building the SDK from source? How are you building the example?